# how to check a folder is empty in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-store

How can I check a folder is empty for local storage?

```
StorageFolder destinationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

How to know `destinationFolder` is empty or not?

Comment: I Binged your query and found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227276.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing one of the following (Both snippets have not been tested):

GetFilesAsync function

```
StorageFolder destinationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
IReadOnlyList <StorageFile> filesInFolder = await destinationFolder.GetFilesAsync();
if(filesInFolder.Count == 0)
     //return empty
else 
     // return not empty
```

GetFiles function

```
 StorageFolder destinationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
 string[] filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(destinationGolder.Path); 
 if (filesInDirectory.Length == 0) 
     //return empty
 else 
     // return not empty
```

Note: this code was not tested.